# CSS Hover change background color on other labels

Tags: css

This is a very tricky one and I'll explain this the best I have an provide full working code.

I have some rating code and what I need it to do is the following:

e.g: Click on the 5th rate (last one) ... It will change it's color and all the ones before it to green.

Now comes the tricky part.

If you now hover on any before the 5th (selected one) I need the selected one (in this case the 5th) and any between where you are hovering to be another background color.

So, if the selected was the 5th and I hovered on the 2nd, then the 5th, 4th and 3rd should have another background color.

I hope I have explained it properly.

Here is a jsfiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/Satch3000/chd6yfzw/1/

and below is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="rating-system1">
    <input type="radio" name='rate' id="star5" />
    <label for="star5"></label>

    <input type="radio" name='rate' id="star4" />
    <label for="star4"></label>

    <input type="radio" name='rate' id="star3" />
    <label for="star3"></label>

    <input type="radio" name='rate' id="star2" />
    <label for="star2"></label>

    <input type="radio" name='rate' id="star1" />
    <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.rating-system1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
} 

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.rating-system1 label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label,
.rating-system1 label:hover ~ label,
.rating-system1 label:hover {
  background: seagreen;
}

.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Your CSS approach to the issue is amazing. Personally I find it easier to do this kind of thing using events. You could try using mouseenter/mouseleave or mouseover/mouseout or a combination of those to accomplish the same thing. Is there any reason for you to strictly use CSS only?

Comment: What should `background-color` of hovered `label` be set to ?

Comment: Trying out something (striped a lot of your CSS out to make it simpler though but you get the idea) https://jsfiddle.net/zrksc8ac/

Comment: @guest271314 - Any backgroud-color will do, as I just want to know how to do it.   Also, I've created a jsfiddle of it, to make it easier to have a play.

Comment: Not possible with pure CSS, because no matter what you can't traverse backwards or upwards through the DOM. You would need to add a hover state class with Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the `background` for `:checked` items when the parent is hovered:

```css
.rating-system1:hover input:checked ~ label{
    background:#666;
}
```

And then override this style to show the default hovered `background` again:

```css
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label,
.rating-system1 label:hover ~ label,
.rating-system1 label:hover,
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label, /* added */
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:hover,         /* added */
.rating-system1 label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label{ /* added */
    background:seagreen;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n8yj1z0/1/).

Comment: I haven't seen this kind of approach before. It seems brilliant. Can you tell me why the response time for the hover effects is rather slow in comparison to javascript hover events?

Comment: Thanx, had my 15 mins there. ;-) Without an example I cannot tell, but maybe because the js selections can be quite simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I messed about with this in the original fiddle and came up with these selectors:

```
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label {
  background:#ccc;
}

.rating-system1:not(:hover) input:checked ~ label,
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
  background:seagreen;
}
```

Not identical to the solution offered by Linus, but it does the same job:

```css
body{background:#222;}

.showcase{
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.rating-system1 {
  width:100%;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2px;
  position: relative;
} 

input{
  display:none;
}

label{
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:10px;
  background:#ccc;
  margin:4px;
  position: relative;
  transition:all .3s;
}

.rating-system1 label:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: inherit;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:all 0.3s;
}

.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label,
.rating-system1 label:hover ~ label,
.rating-system1 label:hover{
  background:seagreen;
}

.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label {
  background:#ccc;
}

.rating-system1:not(:hover) input:checked ~ label,
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
  background:seagreen;
}

.rating-system1 input:checked ~ label:before{
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.text{
  color:#ccc;
  padding:10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
<div class="rating-system1">

<input type="radio" name='rate' id="star5" />
<label for="star5"></label>

<input type="radio" name='rate' id="star4" />
<label for="star4"></label>

<input type="radio" name='rate' id="star3" />
<label for="star3"></label>

<input type="radio" name='rate' id="star2" />
<label for="star2"></label>

<input type="radio" name='rate' id="star1" />
<label for="star1"></label>

</div>

</div>
```